# OpenCV - Removing horizontal dots or lines from image result lower quality image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I follow [Extract horizontal and vertical lines by using morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html) to remove horizontal dots in my image.

The main idea of this solution is `erode` image(remove small or thin lines or dots in horizontal/vertical) and `dilate`. But this will lower the quality of characters in image.

So I want to ask whether there are better solutions to remove dots and do not lose quality of characters in image.

#### original image:

[image: original image]

#### result:

[image: result images]

#### Code:

```
import util
import cv2

grayImage = cv2.imread("00.jpg", 0)

h = float(grayImage.shape[0])

maxVal = 255
blockSize = 15
C = 12.0*(90.0/h)

print("C:" + str(C))

showImages = []

bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grayImage, maxVal, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, blockSize, C)
bw = ~bw

showImages.append(grayImage.copy())
showImages.append(bw.copy())

vertical = bw.copy()

# Specify size on vertical axis
# verticalsize = vertical.shape[0] / 20
verticalsize = 4

# Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))

# Apply morphology operations
vertical = cv2.erode(vertical, verticalStructure, None, (-1,-1))
showImages.append(vertical.copy())

vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure, None, (-1,-1))
showImages.append(vertical.copy())

util.showOpenCVImagesGrid(showImages, 2, 2, titles=["grayImage", "adaptiveThreshold", "after erode", "after dilate"])
```

util:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def showOpenCVImagesGrid(images, x, y, titles=None, axis="on"):
    fig = plt.figure()
    i = 1

    for item in images:
        image = None
        title = None
        if type(images) is list:
            image = item
            if titles is not None:
                title = titles[i - 1]
        elif type(images) is dict:
            image = images[item]
            title = item

        if image is None:
            i += 1
            continue
        copy = image.copy()
        channel = len(copy.shape)

        cmap = None
        if channel == 2:
            cmap = "gray"
        elif channel == 3:
            copy = cv2.cvtColor(copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        elif channel == 4:
            copy = cv2.cvtColor(copy, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)

        fig.add_subplot(x, y, i)

        plt.title(title)
        plt.axis(axis)
        plt.imshow(copy, cmap=cmap)
        i += 1
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no magical solution in case the lines cross the graphics of interest.

But in this case they do not and it suffices to deal with them by using a suitable region of interest.

For instance, you can detect the dots only (top-hat filter) and fit a straight line. By addding a suitable margin, you split the image in two regions, to which you can apply any processing.

For instance, in the image below, the lower part has been cleaned with a 1x5 vertical dilation. You can guess where the splitting edge was set.

[image]

---

Anyway, there is a serious question: do you need to get rid of the dotted line at all ?

Comment: Yes, sometimes its a solid line. Sometimes the line will cross the characters. The solid/dotted line seems will reduced recognition rate.

Comment: And can you give some sample code for first instance?

Comment: What is margin? How to add it? I found the straight line but don't how to add the margin you mentioned.

Comment: @tom: two or three pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.bitwise` operations to just remove line by masking only on the line area. Post removal of line, you can fill the white pixels using `cv2.inpaint` method. You would like to take a look at [documentation here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html)